# kendo ui - create a binding within another binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

In my pursuit to get a binding for an associative array to work, I've made significant progress, but am still blocked by one particular problem.

> I do not understand how to create a binding from strictly javascript

Here is a jsFiddle that shows more details than I have posted here:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/5aHCH/)

Basically, I want to do a new binding within the shown `$.each` function that would be equivalent to this...

```
<div data-template="display-associative-many" data-bind="repeat: Root.Items"></div>
```

Gets turned into this ...

```
<div data-template="display-associative-single" data-bind="source: Root['Items']['One']"></div>
<div data-template="display-associative-single" data-bind="source: Root['Items']['Two']"></div>
<div data-template="display-associative-single" data-bind="source: Root['Items']['Three']"></div>
```

And I am using the `repeat` binding to create that.

Since I cannot bind **to** an associative array, I just want to use a binding to write all of the bindings to the objects in it.

We start again with an **associative array**.

```
var input = {
    "One" : { Name: "One", Id: "id/one" },
    "Two" : { Name: "Two", Id: "id/two" },
    "Three" : { Name: "Three", Id: "id/three" }
};
```

Now, we create a `viewModel` that will contain that associative array.

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
   Name: "View Model",
   Root: {
      Items: input
   }
});

kendo.bind('#example', viewModel);
```

Alarmingly, finding the items to bind was pretty easy, here is my binding so far;

```
$(function(){
    kendo.data.binders.repeat = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
        init: function(element, bindings, options) {
            // detailed more in the jsFiddle

            $.each(source, function (idx, elem) {
                if (elem instanceof kendo.data.ObservableObject) {
                    // !---- THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE -----! //
                    // we want to get a kendo template
                    var template = {};// ...... this would be $('#individual-item')
                    var result = {}; // perhaps the result of a template?
                    // now I need to basically "bind" "elem", which is
                    // basically source[key], as if it were a normal HTML binding
                    $(element).append(result); // "result" should be a binding, basically
                }
            });

            // detailed more in the jsFiddle
        },
        refresh: function() {
            // detailed more in the jsFiddle
        },
        change: function() {
            // detailed more in the jsFiddle
        }
    });
});
```

### I realize that I could just write out the HTML, but that would not perform the actual "binding" for kendo to track it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are attempting to do, but it seemed to me that the custom "repeat" binding was unnecessary. Here's what I came up with. Is this on track with what you are trying to do?

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5aHCH/8/)** is a working jsFiddle example.

**HTML**

```
<div id="example">
  <div data-template="display-associative-many" data-bind="source: Root.Items"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="display-associative-many">
  #for (var prop in data) {#
  #  if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {#
  #    if (data[prop].Id) {#
  <div><span>${data[prop].Id}</span> : <span>${data[prop].Name}</span></div>
  #    }#
  #  }#
  #}#
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
  var input = {
    "One" : { Name: "One", Id: "id/one" },
    "Two" : { Name: "Two", Id: "id/two" },
    "Three" : { Name: "Three", Id: "id/three" }
  };

  var viewModel = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    Id: "test/id",
    Root: {
      Items: input
    }
  });

  kendo.bind('#example', viewModel);
});
```

Comment: Actually, the script you have in the template is what I started with too. I am basically trying to make it cleaner and simpler by wrapping that functionality into bindings. I am pleased that you arrived at the same solution I did, it makes me feel that I'm not trying something stupid, at the very least. I simply don't like mingling that much javascript in my templates. It's frustrating to me, I have difficulty with maintaining them. It's a personal preference, and I want to use the experience as a chance to try making a custom binding.

Comment: Please don't remove your answer, though. This is useful. If I cannot find a way to do what I want with bindings, I will most certainly fall back on the inline javascript. I'm mostly hesitant because I'm not very good at javascript, and everytime I use inline js on kendo templates, I'm terrified that I'm doing something horrible that will cause one of those stupid, laggy websites I can't stand.

Comment: Actually, if I can bother you, how do you feel about the performance of the inline js you showed me? I'm not very knowledgeable in javascript yet, and I really have no idea how to read performance tests to understand what is good and what isn't so far. I'm nervous that this will be horribly inefficient.

Comment: It will be noticeably slower the more items there are to loop through, say over a thousand. To make the iterations perform quicker, make sure to only output HTML for items that pass the `hasOwnProperty()` check and have a defined `Id` property. You don't want the parser to traverse up the `prototype` chain unnecessarily.

Comment: I should only ever need it for about 60 things at any one time, so I'm hoping that won't be a problem.

Comment: You shouldn't notice much of a performance hit at all with ~60 items. It'll feel quite responsive.